# ХЗ или хз? Как верно?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Как пишется слово *ХЗ/хз* в значении *не знаю*?

`Я ХЗ/хз (не знаю), что делать.`

Как думаете, какие буквы нужно использовать: строчные или прописные?

Как вы думаете, совы?

Comment: По идее, нужно ХЗ - литерная аббревиатура же.

Comment: Минус плюс побьёт!

Comment: с другой стороны, если сленг, то можно и с маленькой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать *ХЗ*. Понятное дело, что практически всегда пишут *хз*, так как там, где эта аббревиатура используется, обычно нечасто насчёт грамматики, а именно орфографии думают. Надо, однако, всё-таки — другого варианта грамотного просто нет-с — писать *ХЗ*. Так же и надо писать *ДР* ('день рождения', 'домашнее задание').